# C effect of jumping to specific address to run application

Tags: c

I have a C firmware code for STM32 MCU and i have 2 stack of application stored in different memory address

1. bootloader (0x8000000)
2. main application (0x8004000)

In my bootloader, i have a function that will jump to **0x8004000** address and run that application

But, i want to know, when i jump to that address:

1. bootloader application still running?
2. memory allocated in bootloader remains? or i need to free manually?

Example:

My bootloader has a while loop that blinks a LED, and some allocated ring buffer, so when I jump to my main application, is this loop still running or not? and the memory allocated for the ring buffer will be freed automatically?
or i need to do it manually?

why it happens this way?

Comment: Well, if you jump to your out of your loop. It won't run anymore. BTW how do you jump to the main application ?

Comment: An unconditional jump is an unconditional jump, it doesn't make anything run in the background. For any kind of multi-tasking you need an operating system (or similar) to handle it.

Comment: If you jump to a different address, the program counter will be set to this address and run this part of your code. If there is any multi-tasking and/or multithreading then it might be possible that the other process is still running on a different cpu. But if not, the other program won't run again until you jump back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bootloader is built independently, and takes no further part in the app run after the jump, its allocations, stack, heap are totally irrelevant.since the main app knows nothing abut them and does not care.  It could happily just overwrite them.

If code in the bootloader is to be used by the main app, it may, or may not, require private data.  A reentrant function in the bootloader could be called via a software interrupt with no need for any data dedicated to the bootloader, or the linker scripts for bootloader and main could define data and/or stack sections for private use by the bootloader code.

'LED blinking etc' what?  You do not explain how executin is managed in your design.  Is a multitasker system used by the bootloader, or is the main app supposed to run a thread that calls back?  Either could easily be done - a bootloader thread could call the main app or a main app thread could call bootloader code via a software interrupt.

You have not explained the overall design of your system in sufficient detail.  How are we supposed to know how your system works - you designed it!

Answer (score 1):

When you call a `GOTO` or `JMP` instruction, the controller will just jump to the new location. Any memory in the stack will remain in the stack, and any memory in the heap will still be allocated.

The while loop, however, will not run in the new location, as there is no code to run the loop in the new location.